# Maven test execution gives wrong test count

Tags: java, maven, testing, selenium-webdriver

Maven executing the test scripts successfully but it gives wrong test count

Here is the scenario:

Right now, I have 18 test cases out of which I Skipped 17 while executing through maven and in turns it gives me the following output.

```
Tests run: 32, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 31, Time elapsed: 189.559 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 32, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 31

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 3:27.578s

[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 14 17:46:40 IST 2014

[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/38M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## POM File Structure

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>xxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>xxxx</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
    <useFile>false</useFile>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>abc.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>java-net</id>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
  </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.40.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
    <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>  

    </dependencies>

    </project>
```

Comment: Check how you named your test classes ? Show your pom file.

Comment: I checked and it`s fine.

Comment: Are they named like `*Test.java`, `*TestCase.java` or `Test*.java`? Why do you need having a suitefile ? Can you run the tests without suite file? If you are talking about `Test Cases` do you mean `Test methods within the test class`?

Comment: Yes. classes are named like Test.java and here Test Cases means Test classes where Test methods are written. I used suitefile to run the test parallel and without using suitefile it cannot be achieved.

Comment: That's simply wrong, cause maven-surefire as well as maven-failsafe have configurations to run tests in [paralllel](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkCount).

Comment: I think that`s what I did. I have configured "abc.xml" in maven-surefire to run tests in parallel and abc.xml is the file where I mentioned all the test classes within the specified tags of suitefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for few things :-
1. If you are executing from within eclipse,sometimes this issue is seen.Try executing the same tests from command line.
2. Are you all the tests are getting executed just once,re run maven with -X switch to get complete trace.

Comment: I configured this behavior "<useFile>false</useFile>" in pom.xml to get complete trace but still getting the same output on console

Comment: could you please let me know how to re run maven with -X switch